# How to prevent unwanted request in node js express?

Tags: node.js, express, request, request.querystring

expected request:

```
{
    "name": "Raju",
    "email": "email@email.com"
}
```

Actual:

```
{
    "name": "Raju",
    "email": "email@email.com",
    "xyz" : "xxxx"
}
```

I would like to throw an error or escape for "xyz" in a validation/router level.
Am using the fastest-validator.

is there any other validator supports this feature?

Any help appreciated

Comment: @Lep Paul Share the code snippets wherever you are facing problems.

Comment: @kavigun updated the question. it's a generic issue

Answer (score 0):

You can set `$$strict: true` like below example:

```
const schema = {
    name: { type: "string" }, // required
    $$strict: true // no additional properties allowed
}

v.validate({ name: "John" }, schema); // Valid
v.validate({ name: "John", age: 42 }, schema); // Fail
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. my issue is not additional properties but additional unwanted data set like
name is expected but the country is not expected in the request

{
"name" : "Ram",// required and expected
"country" : "USA" // not required and not expecting in the request
}

Comment: @LeoPaul It will address the same thing, we are validating a request payload schema here

Comment: @Leo Paul  Okay. Please upvote and accept the answer and close the discussion.